# Highcharts still using percentage for y-axis compare

Tags: highcharts

I'm pretty clueless at this point, on some of my charts I am giving these options:

```
var plotOptions, yAxis;

plotOptions = {
  series: {
    compare: 'value'
  }
};

yAxis = {
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return this.value;
    }
  },
  plotLines: [
    {
      value: 0,
      width: 2,
      color: 'silver'
    }
  ]
};
```

And the chart still displays percentages in the y-axis, just without the % sign. I did a console.log of 'this' in the formatter tag, and the value attribute is correct (that is, returning the value instead of a percentage, but it doesn't seem to be applying it to the chart. Any thoughts?

Comment: more code and details required to help you friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just ended up using a spline chart instead. Basically what I was trying to say was that the y-axis was displaying the same values where I used "compare: 'percentage'" or "compare: 'value'", but the spline chart seems to be rendering the labels as the actual data points (4000 as opposed to 25%).